# How to Mock Spring WebFlux WebClient :Error

Tags: spring, rest, unit-testing, mockito

Just a beginner in JUnit testing and I'm writing a small JUnit test coverage using Mockito for WebClient.

Getting Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:8080 `when(responseSpec.bodyToMono(String.class)).thenReturn(monoMock);`
But as I have mocked request.retrieve, It should return me mockData.

Any suggestion on Mocking of request.retrieve.bodyToMono.block() would be helpful.

## Method

```
    public String getProfile(String auth) {
              String userProfileUrl = temp;
            
              WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> request = WebClient.create().get().uri(URI.create(userProfileUrl))
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header(AuthConstants.AUTHORIZATION, authorization);
        
              return request.retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(String.class).block();
        }
```

## Test Case

```
    @Test
    public void testgetUserProfile() {
                
                //Mocking Web Client
            final WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder = Mockito.mock(WebClient.Builder.class);
            final WebClient webClient = Mockito.mock(WebClient.class);
            final WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec headerUriSpecMock = Mockito.mock(WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec.class);
            final WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec headersSpecMock= Mockito.mock(WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.class);
            final WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec bodyUriSpecMock = Mockito.mock(WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec.class);
            final WebClient.RequestBodySpec bodySpecMock = Mockito.mock(WebClient.RequestBodySpec.class);
            final WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec = Mockito.mock(WebClient.ResponseSpec.class);
            final Mono res = Mockito.mock(Mono.class);
             
         
             
            Mockito.when(webClientBuilder.baseUrl(anyString())).thenReturn(webClientBuilder);
            Mockito.when(webClientBuilder.build()).thenReturn(webClient);
            Mockito.when(webClient.get()).thenReturn(headerUriSpecMock);
            Mockito.when(headerUriSpecMock.uri(anyString())).thenReturn(headersSpecMock);
            Mockito.when(headersSpecMock.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).thenReturn(headersSpecMock);
            Mockito.when(headersSpecMock.header(anyString())).thenReturn(headersSpecMock);
            
            Mockito.when(headersSpecMock.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);
        
            Mockito.when(responseSpec.bodyToMono(String.class)).thenReturn(monoMock);
            Mockito.when(monoMock.block()).thenReturn(userDetails);
            
            String tempuserDetails = authorizationUtil.getUserDetails(auth);
            assertNotNull(tempuserDetails);
        }
```

## CALL TRACE : ERROR#

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:326)
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:87)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1162)
    at com.schneider_electric.dces.tnc.util.AuthorizationUtil.getUserProfile(AuthorizationUtil.java:94)
    at com.schneider_electric.dces.tnc.util.AuthorizationUtil.getUserDetails(AuthorizationUtil.java:74)
    at com.schneider_electric.dces.tnc.util.AuthorizationUtilTest.testgetUserProfile(AuthorizationUtilTest.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:89)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:325)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
```

Comment: The NPE is because calling responseSpec.bodyToMono(String.class),  it will return null and then calling block() method on Null cause NPE. you need to first Mock the responseSpec.bodyToMono(String.class)  separately, I guess. e.g  when Mockito.when(responseSpec.bodyToMono(String.class)).thenReturn(whateverItReturns);

then

 Mockito.when(responseSpec.bodyToMono(String.class).block()).thenReturn(userDetails);

Comment: @MohitSharma I'm still getting NPE when I did this:                                               final Mono res = mock(Mono.class);     when(responseSpec.bodyToMono(String.class)).thenReturn(res);
 when(res.block()).thenReturn(userDetails);

Comment: As a general recommendation for testing HTTP clients, I would rather test it with a local HTTP server. Otherwise, it ends up, like your test already does, in a _mocking hell_. The [MockWebServer](https://rieckpil.de/test-spring-webclient-with-mockwebserver-from-okhttp/) can be used for this purpose.